# Force Printing on Legal Size Paper

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, printing

Can this be done programmatically, and without creating a custom PaperSize but using the predefined sizes? The printer is known to support the legal size paper.
Is there a more elegant solution than looping through the printer's paper sizes and scanning for `Legal` substring?

UPDATE
This is what I ended up doing:

```
For i = 0 To PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1
    If PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(i).RawKind = PaperKind.Legal Then
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(i)
    Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a default entry in the [PaperKind enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.paperkind.aspx):

```
PaperLegal
```

(Legal, 8 1/2- by 14-inches.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it is a WinForm app, written in VB.NET. There is no such enumeration. Setting `PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = PaperKind.Legal` does not seem to work.

Comment: Try null'ing the PaperSize first (also cast kind to int), I don't know if it's a bug or what, but I have found in the past that changing the paper size often doesn't work if it has already been set. `PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = null; PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.Legal;`

Comment: Just tried the following, and still no go.   `PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = Nothing PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = CInt(PaperKind.Legal)`

Comment: What about `PaperSize size = new PaperSize();
size.RawKind = CInt(PaperKind.Legal);
PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = size;` ?

Comment: That did work. It is not as clean as referencing the existing PaperSizeCollection items, but at least it works.

Answer (score 2):

I know C# better than VB.NET and in C# I'd do this using LINQ. For my own interest at least here's two attempts at VB.NET LINQ syntax:

```
Dim paperSize as PaperSize = _
    From ps in PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes _
    Where ps.RawKind = PaperKind.Legal _
    Select ps Take 1
If paperSize IsNot Nothing
    DocPrint.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize
End If
```

or

```
Dim paperSize = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes _
                .FirstOrDefault(Function(ps) ps.RawKind = PaperKind.Legal)
If paperSize IsNot Nothing
    DocPrint.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize
End If
```

I'm guessing the syntax so neither of these might work and I've ended up with at least as many lines of code, but it saves writing a loop.