# VB.NET Printing Legal Size

Tags: vb.net, printing, page-size

This program refuses to print legal size. I have spent an embarrassing number of hours researching this problem with no luck. Help would be appreciated. The printer supports Legal printing.  The "Imports System.Drawing.Printing" statement is there.  If I uncomment the PrintPreviewDialog block it previews in Legal size, but prints in Normal size.

EDIT: Program simplified further.  I would appreciate if someone could run this code to determine if it is a program issue or something else. Problem on two different computers, two printers, both which are used for legal size printing on a daily basis in Excel.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click

    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes(2)  '2 has been verified correct, confirmed below


    'PrintDocument1.Print()
    PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    MsgBox(PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.ToString)  ' this verifies the papersize code is correct at run time

    Dim drawFont As New Font("Helvetica", 10)
    Dim rc1 As RectangleF = New RectangleF(250, 650, 400, 50)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", drawFont, Brushes.Black, rc1)

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Actually put legal size paper in the printer and try again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17138213/2319909

Comment: Already tried both solutions with no luck.